# go back to git pre commit state

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and all it's options and terminology are still a bit overwhelming for me. However I have the following situation:

For a new feature in our software I have made new branch (lets call it branch A) on our development branch. When I was finished with the feature I committed my changes and pushed them to branch A. Then I was asked to work on a new feature (feature B) that relied on the feature that I developped in branch A. In all my ignorance I kept working on the same branch and committed the changes (I did not push them to branch A). Now at this moment the review comment from the push I did came in and I have found myself in a sticky situation.

What I want to do is push the review comments that I changed (on my local branch A, that I committed the changes for feature B on) to branch A on the git server, but I have no idea how to get just these review changes there without also pushing the commit of feature B onto it.

Is it possible to go to a state from before my commit of feature B? And if it is, how can I get back to the state of after my commit of feature B after I have pushed the changes to branch A?

And what should I have done? Create a seperate branch (based on branch A) on which to commit my feature B?

Comment: `git checkout -b separate_branch` will create a _new branch_ with your feature B changes. Then `git checkout branch_a` to go back to branch A. Then use `git rebase -i` and delete all the extra feature B commits - they'll still be present in `separate_branch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your situation correctly, you have not pushed any of your B commits to the server. If that is the case, and the last commit you pushed is X, do the following:

1. `git checkout A`
2. `git branch B`
3. `git reset --hard X`  (moves branch A to point to X)

Now, branch B points to the second feature you are working on, and A points to the end of the A feature. Now you can commit your additional changes to A and push.